# Bar graph with ggplot2::geom_col() has random horizontal lines in the bars

Tags: ggplot2, graph

When I am plotting a graph, I am getting vertical lines in my bar graph (please see image). Please advise on how to clear that.[image]

```
ggplot(data = Clean_Bike_Data)+
  geom_col(mapping = aes(x = member_casual, 
                         y = Trip_Duration_Minutes))
```

Thank you in advance for your help,
Avi

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using divvy-tripdata. Let's download the data and read it
to be able to replicate your issue.

```r
download.file(
  "https://divvy-tripdata.s3.amazonaws.com/202004-divvy-tripdata.zip",
  "202004-divvy-tripdata.zip"
)

library(tidyverse)

Clean_Bike_Data <-
  read_csv("202004-divvy-tripdata.zip") |>
  mutate(Trip_Duration_Minutes = difftime(ended_at, started_at, units = "mins"))
```

`geom_col()` stacks rectangle segments for each observation
The borders of the segments are the lines you see.

You can use `geom_bar()` instead of `geom_col()` and specify
`weight = Trip_Duration_Minutes` to avoid the lines.

```r
ggplot(data = Clean_Bike_Data) +
  geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = member_casual,
                         weight = Trip_Duration_Minutes))
```

[image]

Or you can `summarise()` the data before plotting so that you only have
two data rows, one for members and one for casual users.

```r
Clean_Bike_Data |>
  summarise(Trip_Duration_Minutes = sum(Trip_Duration_Minutes),
            .by = member_casual) |>
  ggplot() +
  geom_col(mapping = aes(x = member_casual,
                         y = Trip_Duration_Minutes))
```

[image]